# A deployment error in Xamarin.Forms UWP when deploying from a PC to itself

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-10

When I just installed a Visual Studio 2017 and created my Xamarin.Forms application, it ran fine on my Windows 10 PC. However, I then installed some apps from Steam (which is the only thing I can think of that could change system settings). After that, when I try to create another Xamarin.Forms project, it does not deploy well to my machine and gives the following error:

```
DEP6200: Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found.
SmartDeviceException - Deployment failed because no
device was detected. Make sure a device is connected
and powered on. [0x80131500]
```

Strangely enough, my first app continues to build and run fine, even if I uninstall it from Windows and then deploy it again.

What could be the issue?

Comment: in the project properties of the UWP project, select local device not remote device.

Answer (score 0):

I have just noticed that Visual Studio makes ARM the default architecture. Changing it to "Any CPU" brought back the option to run the app on my machine.

Comment: It's true what they say -- writing down your thoughts helps! :)